# How to embed OpenGL rendering context in MFC Application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, openscenegraph

I want to embed the OpenGL applicaiton, namely openscenegraph library, in MFC MDI application. I've created the MFC application as tabbed MDI document which derives MainForm and ChildForm from CView class, normally swapping the windows handles of control and  OpenGL rendering context(with some initialization) is enough to have scene to be displayed in control. I want the OpenGL scene to be inside of the Child Form.

The problem with above scenario is, firstly I don't know whether is it correct to derive MDI from CView class or different classes are more suitable for that purpose. Secondly with the code below m_hWnd always returns zero so the contexts can not be initialized.

```
   CChildFrame::CChildFrame()
{
    // TODO: add member initialization code here
    osgViewer::Viewer viewer;

    //osg::ref_ptr<osg::GraphicsContext::Traits> traits = new osg::GraphicsContext::Traits;
    RECT rect;
    HWND hw;    

    hw = m_hWnd;

    ::GetWindowRect(m_hWnd, &rect);

    osg::ref_ptr<osg::GraphicsContext::Traits> traits = new osg::GraphicsContext::Traits;

    // Init the Windata Variable that holds the handle for the Window to display OSG in.
    osg::ref_ptr<osg::Referenced> windata = new osgViewer::GraphicsWindowWin32::WindowData(m_hWnd);

    // Setup the traits parameters
    traits->x = 0;
    traits->y = 0;
    traits->width = rect.right - rect.left;
    traits->height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
    traits->windowDecoration = false;
    traits->doubleBuffer = true;
    traits->sharedContext = 0;
    traits->setInheritedWindowPixelFormat = true;
    traits->inheritedWindowData = windata;

    // Create the Graphics Context
    osg::GraphicsContext* gc = osg::GraphicsContext::createGraphicsContext(traits.get());

    // Init a new Camera (Master for this View)
    osg::ref_ptr<osg::Camera> camera = new osg::Camera;

    // Assign Graphics Context to the Camera
    camera->setGraphicsContext(gc);

    // Set the viewport for the Camera
    camera->setViewport(new osg::Viewport(traits->x, traits->y, traits->width, traits->height));

    // Set projection matrix and camera attribtues
    camera->setClearMask(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    camera->setClearColor(osg::Vec4f(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.4f, 1.0f));
    camera->setProjectionMatrixAsPerspective(
        30.0f, static_cast<double>(traits->width) / static_cast<double>(traits->height), 1.0, 1000.0);

    // Add the Camera to the Viewer
    //mViewer->addSlave(camera.get());
    viewer.setCamera(camera.get());

    // Add the Camera Manipulator to the Viewer
    viewer.setCameraManipulator(new osgGA::OrbitManipulator());

    osg::ref_ptr<osg::Group> root = new osg::Group;
    osg::ref_ptr<osg::Geode> geode = new osg::Geode;
    geode->addDrawable(new osg::ShapeDrawable(new osg::Box(osg::Vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -0.5f), 100.0f, 100.0f, 1.0f)));

    root->addChild(geode.get());

    viewer.setSceneData(root.get());
    viewer.realize();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried moving your initialization code to OnCreate rather than in the constructor?  m_hWnd will always be NULL in the constructor.

Comment: Yes I tried that and it now returns logical value which seems more like a handle, but there is another discrepancy in that related to OSG. It never shows the scene, that is, scene gets never renderedI believe, that this is due to once called OnCreate call, because its called only once during creation, I placed the `while ( !viewer.done()) { viewer.frame()}` code snippet into OnPaint of CChildFrame but interestingly the OnPaint is never fired in CChildFrame window.